# How to find invariable addresses in cheat engine

Tags: cheat-engine

I would be interested to know some way with the Cheat Engine, to be able to change a value, which within the game, does not change, that is, it is not like the life that is decreasing, nor as the bullets that are increasing. It is a fixed value. The main problem is that when looking for that value, the result is more than 100k so I would like to know how I can decrease that amount.

Comment: "Decrease that amount" how? There really are that many memory locations that don't change.

Comment: What exactly does that value do?

Comment: I mean, decrease the amount of search, limit the EC in some way so that for example (in other programs it could be done), just edit what was being seen at that time or what was happening at that time and not All game memory.

Comment: It is a percentage that if it goes up gives you an object within the game. The problem is that it is an event already over, and therefore can no longer vary.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce results when your value doesn't change you need to keep playing the game or moving through as many different menus/positions/items as possible while continually scanning for "Unchanged Value".

This should definitely take it down from 100k as there are without doubt nowhere near that many unchanging values.